# How can I sort this array of objects with many properties in PHP?

Tags: php, sorting

I have an array that contains multiple objects with many properties.

I want to sort it in PHP base on two object properties

Here's a sample array of objects to give you an idea of what data i'm dealing with:

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object (
        [username] => user98
        [sender_id] => 98
        [date_sent] => 2012-07-25 00:52:11
        [not_read] => 0
    )
    [1] => stdClass Object (
        [username] => user87
        [sender_id] => 87
        [date_sent] => 2012-07-25 00:59:15
        [not_read] => 1
    )
    [2] => stdClass Object (
        [username] => user93
        [sender_id] => 93
        [date_sent] => 2012-07-25 00:52:13
        [not_read] => 2
    )
    [3] => stdClass Object (
        [username] => user5
        [sender_id] => 5
        [date_sent] => 2012-07-25 00:52:16
        [not_read] => 0
    )
)
```

I need to sort it resulting to this array:

```
Array (
    [1] => stdClass Object (
        [username] => user87
        [sender_id] => 87
        [date_sent] => 2012-07-25 00:59:15
        [not_read] => 1
    )
    [2] => stdClass Object (
        [username] => user93
        [sender_id] => 93
        [date_sent] => 2012-07-25 00:52:13
        [not_read] => 2
    )
    [3] => stdClass Object (
        [username] => user5
        [sender_id] => 5
        [date_sent] => 2012-07-25 00:52:16
        [not_read] => 0
    )

    [0] => stdClass Object (
        [username] => user98
        [sender_id] => 98
        [date_sent] => 2012-07-25 00:52:11
        [not_read] => 0
    )


)
```

The sorting is based on the date property and the not_read property of the object, the not_read > 0 is prioritized first in the sorting, then it will look at the date_sent property and sort it on the latest date_sent. Note that it is not based on who has the higher not_read property.

Then those with 0 not_read property will be sorted by latest date_sent.

Can anyone help me with this program?

thanks a lot of looking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function sortByDate($a, $b)
{
    if($a->not_read > 0 && $b->not_read == 0)
        return -1;
    if($b->not_read > 0 && $a->not_read == 0)
        return 1;
    if ($a->not_read == 0 && $b->not_read == 0 || $a->not_read > 0 && $b->not_read > 0){
        if(strtotime($a->date_sent) > strtotime($b->date_sent))
            return -1;
        if(strtotime($a->date_sent) < strtotime($b->date_sent))
            return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

usort($array_to_sort, 'sortByDate');
```

Note: I would of made an edit to Patrick's but I wasn't sure if mine even worked.  He was on the right track.

Comment: @MatthewScragg the conditional isn't correct for the `not_read` property in your sort function.  You checking only if the two comparing objects have a `not_read` property of > 0 and the other MUST have a `not_read` property of 0, in the example the OP gives there are three values given for `not_read`: 0,1,2.  The sort function will not sort those objects properly.

Comment: @Patrick Read the OP again, it appears he doesn't care what the not_read is, just as long not_read > 0 is in front AND still sorted by date.

Comment: @MatthewScragg ah, missed that part.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a user-defined sort function:

```
function sortByDate($a, $b)
{
    if($a->not_read > $b->not_read)
        return 1;
    if($a->not_read < $b->not_read)
        return -1;
    if(strtotime($a->date_sent) > strtotime($b->date_sent))
        return 1;
    if(strtotime($a->date_sent) < strtotime($b->date_sent))
        return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

Then call it with [usort](http://us.php.net/usort):

```
usort($array_to_sort, 'sortByDate');
```

The array passed in will now be sorted.

Comment: i got confused from this code, i mean if the if statement in the $a->not_read returns already, then how will the code reach to the strtotime?

Comment: @KevinLee since your first sorting criteria is for the `not_read` property, the `date_sent` doesn't matter.  Only for the objects where the `not_read` property are the same would you need to worry about the `date_sent` property.